# Quick question about changing the font of the drop cap letter in my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, fonts, blogs, drop-cap

Quick question about how to make my dang WordPress blog look instantly better than it currently does!

I use Unna font for my headers and Jost font for the body text. I use drop cap for the first paragraph of my blog articles.

Obviously, because I use Jost font for the body font, the drop cap letter is Jost. I want it to be Unna font, instead.

How would I (slash, is it possible) to change the drop cap letter to a different font than the rest of the body’s font? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a correct answer since we don't see your code, but you can use something like that:

```
p::first-letter {
   font-family: 'Unna', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Oh I’m sorry I totally spaced on that. I use elementor and Astra as my theme and am still learning to code I’m still new to this I apologize :) can I ask perhaps a dumb follow up question? :/ what chunk of code would I need to show you to better explain myself? I’m sorry I feel stupid asking these elementary questions I super appreciate your/anyone’s help though for reals! Thanks